# Change Active Color Image With JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please take a look at [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w92of6em/).

I've tried to write some JS to make it so that when one of the colors in the bottom row is clicked on, the image in the top row changes. I included the images that it should change to over in the JS (they're all saved on imgur).

Unfortunately, nothing is happening. What is wrong?

**HTML**

```
<div class = "row">
  <div class="active">
  <img id="active-color" src="https://i.imgur.com/wSRf1kZ.png"/>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="other-color">
  <img id ="black" src="https://i.imgur.com/NzYkFkO.png" onclick="changeImage()"/>
  </div>

  <div class="other-color">
  <img id ="green" src="https://i.imgur.com/D2uiTnX.png" onclick="changeImage()"/>
  </div>

  <div class="other-color">
  <img id="pink" src="https://i.imgur.com/8oTZjc9.png"  onclick="changeImage()"/>
  </div>

  <div class="other-color">
  <img id="blue" src="https://i.imgur.com/oFSqOUp.png" src="https://i.imgur.com/D2uiTnX.png" onclick="changeImage()"/>
  </div>

  <div class="other-color">
  <img id="brown" src="https://i.imgur.com/xbj7l5p.png" src="https://i.imgur.com/D2uiTnX.png" onclick="changeImage()"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.other-color {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
}
```

**JS**

```
//green on white
//https://i.imgur.com/04hDBLJ.png

//pink on white
//https://i.imgur.com/FG9voBX.png

//blue on white
//https://i.imgur.com/SmNcXqY.png

//brown on white
//https://i.imgur.com/erFfzyQ.png

function changeImage() {
//if black, stay black
if (document.getElementById("active-color").src == "https://i.imgur.com/NzYkFkO.png") 
{
document.getElementById("active-color").src = "https://i.imgur.com/wSRf1kZ.png";
}
//if green, turn green
if (document.getElementById("active-color").src == "https://i.imgur.com/D2uiTnX.png") 
{
document.getElementById("active-color").src = "https://i.imgur.com/04hDBLJ.png";
}
//if pink, turn pink
if (document.getElementById("active-color").src == "https://i.imgur.com/8oTZjc9.png") 
{
document.getElementById("active-color").src = "https://i.imgur.com/FG9voBX.png";
}
//if blue, turn blue
if (document.getElementById("active-color").src == "https://i.imgur.com/D2uiTnX.png") 
{
document.getElementById("active-color").src = "https://i.imgur.com/SmNcXqY.png";
}
//if brown, turn brown
if (document.getElementById("active-color").src == "https://i.imgur.com/D2uiTnX.png") 
{
document.getElementById("active-color").src = "https://i.imgur.com/erFfzyQ.png";
}
}
```

Also any jQuery solutions would be fine.

Comment: The value starts as `https://i.imgur.com/wSRf1kZ.png` but you never check for that so all the conditions fail.

Comment: `active-color` is `https://i.imgur.com/wSRf1kZ.png` which doesn't match any of your if conditionals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**html:**

```
<div class="other-color">
    <img id="black" src="https://i.imgur.com/NzYkFkO.png" onclick="changeImage(this.src)"/>
</div>
```

**js:**

```
function changeImage(src) {
        //if black, stay black
        if (src == "https://i.imgur.com/NzYkFkO.png"){
        document.getElementById("active-color").src = "https://i.imgur.com/wSRf1kZ.png";
    }
        //if green, turn green
        if (src == "https://i.imgur.com/D2uiTnX.png"){
        document.getElementById("active-color").src = "https://i.imgur.com/04hDBLJ.png";
    }   //if pink, turn pink
        if (src == "https://i.imgur.com/8oTZjc9.png"){
        document.getElementById("active-color").src = "https://i.imgur.com/FG9voBX.png";
    }   //if blue, turn blue
        if (src == "https://i.imgur.com/oFSqOUp.png"){
        document.getElementById("active-color").src = "https://i.imgur.com/SmNcXqY.png";
    }   //if brown, turn brown
        if (src == "https://i.imgur.com/xbj7l5p.png"){
        document.getElementById("active-color").src = "https://i.imgur.com/erFfzyQ.png";
    }
}
```

Comment: That's close but the image still needs to be different from the image that gets clicked on - i.e. it still needs to have the white square in its background.

Comment: I realized that the images weren't loading in Codepen. Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w92of6em/) where they load correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to transfer the data of what was clicked to the function in order to do your checks. As it is now, there is no way to check what element was clicked in your Javascript and fetch its src. Hope this helps.

**html:**

```
<div class="other-color">
    <img id="blue" src="https://i.imgur.com/oFSqOUp.png" onclick="changeImage(this.src)"/>
</div>
```

**js:**

```
function changeImage(src) {
    if (src == "https://i.imgur.com/oFSqOUp.png"){
        document.getElementById("active-color").src = "https://i.imgur.com/SmNcXqY.png";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks, that makes sense, but please see [updated codepen](https://codepen.io/HappyHands31/pen/ZdbOMo). Unfortunately something is still not working.

Comment: Hi, your onclick function still doesn't parse data to your Javascript so `onclick="changeImage()"` should be `onclick="changeImage(this.src)"` in the img tag.